# Only use where condition if string parameter is not null or empty string

Tags: mysql

I have a query and I only want to use the where conditions if the parameters are not null or empty strings.

```
select
users.user_id,
users.fname,
users.lname,
Certifications.certName,
skills.skillName
from users
left join Certifications on users.user_id = Certifications.user_id
left join specializations on users.user_id = specializations.user_id
left join skills on skills.user_id = skills.user_id
where
(Certifications.certName is not null and Certifications.certName like 'CCNA Routing and Switching')  or 
(skills.skillName is not null and skills.skillName like '') or
(users.location is not null and users.location like '') 
group by users.user_id
```

So if the search term for `skillName` and `location` is empty I don't want to include those in the `where` clause.

Comment: Where are these search terms coming from?  How are you generating this query?

Comment: Maybe you could try something like `($searchTerm != '' AND skills.skillName like '$searchTerm')`?

Comment: I have a jquery method that passed json data to a php file that actually calls to the query to the database.

Comment: Then have PHP add only the clauses it needs when generating the query.

Comment: what Rocket said ↑ . Otherwise you are just saying, oh, sorry, just kidding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must build your query only with the parameters that are not null

```
$whereClauses = array();
if (!empty($certifications)) {
   $whereClauses[] = 'Certifications.certName like ?';
}
if (!empty($skillName)) {
   $whereClauses[] = 'skills.skillName like ?';
}
if (!empty($location)) {
   $whereClauses[] = 'users.location like ?';
}
$query .= implode(' OR ', $whereClauses);
```

Then, of course, you need to bind the corresponding parameters to the ? characters

Answer (score 2):

You know this in the front-end. Adjust accordingly.